# React-hook-form регистрация и получение ref элемента

Tags: javascript, reactjs, form, ref

**У меня есть компонент Input, использующий react-hook-form**

```
const InputUI = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const {
    form,
    label,
    invalidMessage,
    cornerLabel,
    className,
    validationRules,
    invalidMessageClassName,
    disabled,
    inputStyles,
    labelStyles,
    ...inputProps
  } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const inputId = inputProps.id ? inputProps.id : _.uniqueId('input');
  const isInvalid = form.errors[inputProps.name];

  return (
    <FormControl fullWidth variant="filled">
      <InputLabel
        htmlFor={inputId}
        classes={{
          root: `${classes.label} ${labelStyles}`,
          shrink: classes.shrink,
        }}
      >
        <Caption size={CaptionSizes.s} color="gray50">
          {label}
        </Caption>
      </InputLabel>
      <FilledInput
        id={inputId}
        disableUnderline
        disabled={disabled}
        error={isInvalid}
        inputRef={form.register(validationRules)}
        classes={{
          root: `${classes.root} ${className}`,
          focused: classes.focused,
          input: `${classes.input} ${inputStyles}`,
          error: classes.error,
          disabled: classes.disabled,
        }}
        {...inputProps}
        endAdornment={(
          <InputAdornment
            position="end"
            classes={{ root: classes.endAdornment }}
          >
            <Caption
              size={CaptionSizes.s}
              weight={CaptionWeights.medium}
              color="gray50"
            >
              {cornerLabel}
            </Caption>
          </InputAdornment>
        )}
      />
      {isInvalid && (
        <FormHelperText classes={{ root: classes.errorMessage }}>
          <InvalidMessage
            msg={invalidMessage}
            invalidMessageClassName={invalidMessageClassName}
          />
        </FormHelperText>
      )}
    </FormControl>
  );
});
```

**Для регистрации инпута используется:**

```
inputRef={form.register(validationRules)}
```

**Я использую этот компонент в разных частях проекта и мне нужно получить ref инпута в родительском компоненте. Мне нужно сфокусировать инпут при определенном событии. Как получить ref в родительском компоненте? Есть другие способы для фокуса инпута при событии?**

Answer (score 0):

Внутри компонента инпута присваиваю значению ref.current (прокинутого через forwardRef) полученное значение из формы:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref) {
      ref.current = form.control.fieldsRef.current[inputProps.name].ref
    }
  }, [])
```